# CSS Gradient not filling container after elements are added via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently writing a placeholder page that will be used inside a game through a HTML panel and changed dynamically with the game code.

I am currently working with the search function for the page and am having trouble with the gradient being used in the background. I am using javascript in order to dynamically fill in the search results (will later be injected via the game code to show the correct things).

When the javascript adds in the filler text after the search box is used (again, placeholder) the gradient does not dynamically change its end points to fill the new width of the box. It begins a brand new gradient in the new space. When I open the chrome inspect element console however it updates the gradient to fill the box (the game only supports webkit, hence why it is only built with webkit elements in mind).

Am I able to simulate what the chrome inspect element console does to the gradient in javascript?

HTML

```
<section id="database-search">  
        <form action="javascript:showResults()">
            <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search for Item..." checked="checked"></input>
        </form>
        <section id="search-results">
            <span id="search_results"></span>
        </section>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.database-search {
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e1e1e), color-stop(30%, #373737), color-stop(60%, #373737), color-stop(100%, #1e1e1e));
}
```

Javascript

```
function showResults() {
            document.getElementById('search_results').innerHTML = 'No Results Found.';
        }
```

Thanks!
edit: posted wrong bit of CSS, updated!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code. It seems it's working fine.

HTML

```
<section id="database-search">  

            <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search for Item..." checked="checked"></input>
           <button value="click">Click</button>

        <section id="search-results">
            <span id="search_results"></span>
        </section>
    </section>
```

JavaScript

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    document.getElementById('search_results').innerHTML = 'No Results Found.';
});
```

//i have used jquery to wire the events

css

```
#database-search {
                       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1e1e1e), color-stop(30%, #373737), color-stop(60%, #373737), color-stop(100%, #1e1e1e));

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc5VT/1/

It would be fine if you have any more clarifications regarding your question.